# Оптимизация php кода рассылки

Tags: php, оптимизация

Всем привет, еще не сильна в PHP, вот я сделала вот такой простенький скрипт для рассылки по своей группе ВК:

```
  <?php
const VK_KEY = ""; //тот самый длинный ключ доступа сообщества
const VERSION = "5.80"; //ваша версия используемого api
$host = ''; // адрес сервера 
$database = ''; // имя базы данных
$user = ''; // имя пользователя
$password = ''; // пароль

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Ошибка : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

include "vk_api.php";

$message = $_POST['message'];
$attach =$_POST['atach'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

        if ($password == 'ПАРОЛЬ') {
                $vk = new vk_api(VK_KEY, VERSION);
                $baza = $mysqli->query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `user`");

                    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($baza);
                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($baza)) {
                                   $vk->sendMessage($row[0],$message,$attach);
                         }

             mysqli_free_result($result);
                header('Location: http://site.ru/spam.html');
        }else{
            header('Location: http://idinahuj.com/');
        }



?>
```

Cуть скрипта, рассылка сообщений пользователям, которые есть в базе, соответственно ID подгружаются из БД. Как можно оптимизировать скрипт, чтобы он не умирал при большом объеме ?

Comment: Обрабатывать частями. Каждый запуск обрабатывает Х записей, следующий - следующие Х и т.д.

Comment: Помните, что ваш хостер может трактовать рассылку как спам и блокировать все что вы отправляете.